# Web scraper in Python for multiple articles of the same webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

I want to download multiple articles at once and save into a csv file.
I have set a limit for 5 pages of the website on the specific topic, but I am not sure it is suppose to be so long. Each page has 10 articles, so it is supposed to be for 50 articles in total.

The code has been running for more than one hour now, is this normal?

Thank you.

I am using Google Colab for the code:

```
#Generalized function to get all news-related articles from a Nasdaq webpage
def get_news_urls(links_site):
  resp = requests.get(links_site)
  
  if not resp.ok:
    return None
 
  html = resp.content
 

  soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'lxml')
 

  links = soup.find_all('a')
 
  urls = [link.get('href') for link in links]
  urls = [url for url in urls if url is not None]
 

  news_urls = [url for url in urls if '/article/' in url]
 
  return news_urls
```

```
def scrape_all_articles(ticker , upper_page_limit = 5):
  landing_site = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/' + ticker + '/news-headlines'
 
  all_news_urls = get_news_urls(landing_site)
 
  current_urls_list = all_news_urls.copy()
 
  index = 2
 

  while (current_urls_list is not None) and (current_urls_list != []) and \
        (index <= upper_page_limit):
        
        current_site = landing_site + '?page=' + str(index)
        current_urls_list = get_news_urls(current_site)
 
 
        all_news_urls = all_news_urls + current_urls_list
 
        index = index + 1
 
  all_news_urls = list(set(all_news_urls))
 
    #Now, we have a list of urls, we need to actually scrape the text
  all_articles = [scrape_news_text(news_url) for news_url in all_news_urls]
 
  return all_articles
```

```
nflx_articles = scrape_all_articles('nflx' , 5)
```

Comment: Are you using PyCharm? Using the PyCharm debugger should give you the ability to see where exactly your code is getting stuck. ...EDIT: Oh, I see you are using Google Colab. I am not sure it has as many robust debugging tools.

Comment: Be careful you're not trying to scrape the whole www with links containing `/article`

Comment: Nestor, could you be more specific, please? You mean the url is missing from /article?